# the code doesn't display and doesn't run either

Tags: c++

Below is a program that has class definitions for Item, Customer and Sales. The main simply creates object object of each class and test its member functions. Modify the main program such that it provides a menu driven interface where user can create objects of Item, Customer and a complete a sales transaction with the sales object.The program should also have an option for display the records of items,customers and sales.To make your program more useful,include file handling such that when objects are created for Items,Customers and Transaction,the user will be prompted to save the recordon the file or not.

here's the code it's not displaying anything pleasee help i'm running it by Dev c++

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class Item {
  int itemCode;

private:
  double price;
  double discount;

protected:
  int qtyOnStock;
  char *name;

public:
  Item() {
    itemCode = 0;
    strcpy(name, "UNKNOWN");
    price = 0;
    discount = 0;
    qtyOnStock = 100;
  }
  void setItemCode(int c) { itemCode = c; }
  int getItemCode() { return itemCode; }
  double getPrice() { return price; }
  void setPrice(double p) { price = p; }
  void setDiscount(double d) { discount = d; }
  double getDiscount(double d) { return ((d < 20 ? d : 20) / 100 * price); }
  void setName(char *n) { name = n; }
  char *getName() { return name; }

  void setQtyOnStock(int q) { qtyOnStock = q; }
  int getQtyOnStock() { return qtyOnStock; }
};
class Customer {
private:
  int id;
  char *name;
  char *contactNo;
  int type;

public:
  Customer() {
    id = 0;
    strcpy(contactNo, "No Num");
    strcpy(name, "No Name");
    type = 0;
  }
  void setId(int newId) { id = newId; }
  int getId() { return id; }
  void setName(char *n) { strcpy(name, n); }
  char *getName() { return name; }
  void setContactNo(char *c) { strcpy(contactNo, c); }
  char *getContactNo() { return name; }
};
class Sales {
private:
  Item item;
  Customer cust;
  char *date;
  int qtySold;

public:
  Sales() { date = "mm-dd-yyyy"; }
  void setItem(Item newItem) { item = newItem; }
  Item getItem() { return item; }
  void setCustomer(Customer newCust) { cust = newCust; }
  Customer getCustomer() { return cust; }
  void setDate(char *newDate) { strcpy(date, newDate); }
  char *getDate() { return date; }
  void setQtySold(int newQty) { qtySold = newQty; }
  int getQtySold() { return qtySold; }
};
int main() {
  Item item1;
  Customer cust1;
  Sales sales1;
  item1.setItemCode(143);
  item1.setName("Ballpen");
  item1.setPrice(12.5);
  item1.setQtyOnStock(250);
  cust1.setId(123);
  cust1.setName("Juan dela Cruz");
  sales1.setItem(item1);
  sales1.setCustomer(cust1);
  sales1.setDate("10-27-2018");
  sales1.setQtySold(98);
  item1.setQtyOnStock(item1.getQtyOnStock() - sales1.getQtySold());
  system("cls");
  cout << sales1.getItem().getName() << endl << item1.getQtyOnStock();
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you try to pare this down to a more minimal example? What happens if you just use one class, and instead of trying to call `setSomething` a dozen times before writing output, you just check that the results of `setItemCode` are what you expect?

Comment: Also unless it's an absolute requirement of the program, I would strongly suggest replacing all the `char*` stuff in all the classes with `std::string`. Right now stuff like all your constructors are just plain wrong because you're using `strcpy` incorrectly. The "replace everything with `std::string`" fix is much easier than the "make all the C-style stuff work correctly" fix.

Comment: Don't include the archaic DOS header `conio.h` just to use `getch()` to hold the terminal window open on windows. That makes your code 100% non-portable to anything but DOS/windows. Just delete the line `#include <conio.h>` and replace `getch();` with `std::cin.get();`. It will do the same thing in a portable way. You may also want to remove `system("cls");` -- all it does is output a screen full of newlines just to give the appearance it is "clearing" the screen. When you need to post your output, it's much easier to do without 25 blank lines between every output.

Comment: Is this your homework? Are you required to use C-style strings? Did they teach how to work with C-style strings in class, or provide references for self-learning?

Comment: Reading the description of your assignment it seems that you already started of with a program and were required to edit it. Please make clear which parts of the shown code are your edits, i.e. what is the initial code.

Answer (score 0):

In your Item class:

```
protected:
  int qtyOnStock;
  char *name;

public:
  Item() {
    itemCode = 0;
    strcpy(name, "UNKNOWN");
    price = 0;
    discount = 0;
    qtyOnStock = 100;
  }
```

`name` is an unitialized char pointer so copying to it will result in UB.

change `char* name` to `std::string name`, replace `strcpy(...) name = "UNKNOWN"`.

Normally though you initialize member variables like this:

```
  Item() 
  : itemCode(0), itemCode(0), name("UNKNOWN"), price(0), discount(0), qtyOnStrock(100) 
  {}
```

a newer compiler lets you initialize in other ways like when declared e.g.:

```
protected:
  int qtyOnStock{100};
  std::string name{"UNKNOWN"};
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The main and biggest proble is that you do C-style string handling with `char*` and even that in a wrong way.

If you would enable all warning in your compiler, it would already tell you the problems. My VS2019 gives 15 errors, 1 warning and 7 messages, when I try to compile your code. Please see:
[image]

So, the main problem is that you are using `char*` that are not initialzed, meaning they point to somehwere, and that you do not allocate memory to store your strings.

So all your `strcpy` functions will fail and probably crash your system. Also the assignments to a `char*` will fail in most cases.

You will overwrite some random memory.

All this can be immediately fixed, without big problems, if you would use `std::string` instead of `char*`. Because `char*` are that error prone, C++ introduced the `std::string`, so, please use it.

Sometimes you have C++ teachers that want you to use `char*`. Those teachers should be fired. But if you really need to use `char*`. Then you must allocate memory, before coping data.

Let us assume that you have a string "myName" and you want to copy that.

```
char* name{};
name = new char[strlen(myName)+1];  // +1 for the trailing '\0'
strcpy(name, myName);

// ...
// ...
// Do stuff
// ...
// ...

delete [] name;  // Release memory at the end
```

But as said. Simply use `std::string`

Your program as is, cannot work. You need a major refactoring.